# Angular mat-slider track fill customize with gradient

Tags: css, angular, linear-gradients, mat-slider

I have to customize a angular math-slider track fill  with a gradient. I have try to override the mat-slider-track-fill has code below but it doesn't works.

```
.mat-slider-track-fill
 {
    background-color: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255,68,0,0.2637429971988795) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 62%, rgba(0,164,255,0.3477766106442577) 100%); !important;
 }
```

[image]

My end result should be a track bar like this. If I use the "fixed color" (ex. yellow, red..) it works but if I try to use the gradient it doesn't. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with your code:

1. you have a semicolon right before `!important` which should be removed
2. linear-gradient should be applied to css attribute property `background`, not `background-color`. Exchanging this property should resolve the issue.